# Two applications using framebuffer

Tags: linux, framebuffer

I'm writing a set of Linux framebuffer applications for embedded hardware. The main application runs on tty1 from /etc/inittab (for now it's just a touchscreen test) and is supposed to run permanently. The second application is executed from acpid when the power button is pressed, and it's supposed to ask user if he really want to shut the device down, and read user answer from a touchscreen. What I want is that the second application would takeover framebuffer while it runs, and then release it and restore the state of screen, so the main application can continue without restart.

Is this scenario possible with 2 different applications, and how should they interact ? Now the second application just can't draw anything while the main application is running.

I know I can kill and restart main application, or move poweroff notification to the main application and have acpid just sending a signal to it, but those solutions don't seem to be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would of course be to have THREE applications, one that does the actual framebuffer interaction, and the other two just sends messages (in some form, e.g. through a pipe, socket or similar). This is how "window managers" and similar usually works (but much more complicated, of course)

Comment: That's a nice way, but it requires some exchange protocol to be developed, and such protocol may become quite complex after some time.